# How to set AppUserModelId of application pinned to Taskbar?

Tags: .net, taskbar, windows-10-desktop

We have an internal application which we distribute as a raw executable on a server which people either run directly or copy locally and then run.  When run, the application copies itself to the user's temp directory and then executes that executable.  (We do this because lots of people were running it from the server and leaving it up, making it impossible to update the executable on the server.)

Each application window sets the App User Model ID to a specified GUID.

Unfortunately, if a user pins the application to the taskbar (under Windows 10) and then executes the application, they get two copies of the icon on the task bar - the pinned application and their executing application.

I'm fairly certain this is because the pinned program has no App User Model ID and application's windows do have that specific value.

Is there any way (either through Windows or programmatically), that I can set the App User Model ID of the taskbar shortcut so I can make it match the windows?  It feels like I should be able to give the application an AppuserModelId that the Windows can access without executing the app.

If it matters, this is a C# (.NET) application.

Other Info: If I open up shell:appfolder, the application does not appear unless I also pin it to the Start menu.  If I do so, I can see the AppUserModelId, but it is simply that path to the application and I can find no means of setting it to the proper GUID.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have a workaround, but I would love to know why it works:

For sake of clarity, assume the application was originally stored in "C:\Apps".

Originally, the program was pinned to the Taskbar by right-clicking on its location in "C:\Apps" in an Explorer window and selecting "Pin to Taskbar".  This gave their shortcut location as "C:\Apps".

If I unpinned it, and instead ran the program (which now created a Window with the correct AppUserModelId), and then right-clicked the icon and chose "Pin to Taskbar" I get a task bar icon that doesn't suffer the "doubled icon" problem, presumably because both the running program and the new task bar icon point to the temp directory.

However, if I manually change the shortcut on the taskbar to point to the "C:\Apps", it still doesn't suffer from the "doubled icon" problem, and now points to the correct location for the application!

Problem solved, but my confusion remains.

Did I solve the problem by pinning the application icon to the taskbar only after the window had been assigned an AppUserModelId by the program?  And then back to my original question.  Is there any way of the user pinning the application to the task bar without running it, yet still avoid the "doubled icon" problem?